# Why is it possible to cancel $1$ in $-1 \leq 1-x^2 \leq 1$

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate the domain of 
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 
\arcsin(|1-x^2|) - \sqrt{2}x \text{ if } x < 0 \\ 
\ln(\frac{x^2+a}{x^2-2}) \text{ if } x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
When calculating the domain of $\arcsin(|1-x^2|)$, we say that $$-1 \leq 1-x^2 \leq 1. \space\space\space\text{(1)}$$

My professor cancelled out the $'1'$, so he calculated $$-1 \leq 1-x^2. \space\space\space\text{(2)}$$

Why is this possible? When we calculate equation $1$, we get $0$ and $+\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$. For equation $2$, we only get $+\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$. Will it be wrong if I calculate equation $2$?

Comment: For equation (2), you get the entire interval $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: Note that $1-x^2 \le 1$ is true for all $x$, so it makes no difference in describing the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1-x^2\le1\iff x^2\ge0$$
But the latter is trivially true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. You seem to be solving the equation $1-x^2=1$ but this is not the same as solving the inequality $1-x^2\le1$.